# Angular 2 glyphicon not showing up

Tags: angular, angular-components

Trying to render a star icon on the main page, but it's not showing up (it's the only thing that should be on the page).  Pretty new so I'm still learning.  Please forgive the absolute stupidity of this question.

So I have created the following component called AppComponent:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:  `<i class="glyphicon" 
        [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite" 
        [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
        (click)="onClick()
        "></i>`
})

export class AppComponent  {
  @Input() isFavorite = false;

  onClick(){
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

I have the server running on listening mode, but it's not showing me the star on the webbrowser.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and here is my app.module.ts class:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thoughts, suggestions, ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `@Input()` is unnecessary here. It's used to pass data down from parent components. (i.e., `<my-app [isFavorite]="true"></my-app>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout your css define: load from cdn, load global css, ...

as i see, you using bootstrap glyphicon, if you using cdn, just add cdn link to index.html. else if you load local css, you need serve `fonts` directory as well.
btw,

```
(click)="onClick()
    "
```

change to:

```
(click)="onClick()"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to do a little digging on the cdn stuff but these were the missing lines in my code

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ngClass` instead?

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:  `<i class="glyphicon"
        [ngClass]="isFavorite ? 'glyphicon-star' : 'glyphicon-star-empty'"
        (click)="onClick()"></i>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @Input() isFavorite = false;

  onClick(){
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

I tend to use a `[class.CLASSNAME]` binding when I need to **toggle a UNIQUE class**, e.g. an `active` class on a link. Since in your case, you need to **decide between TWO classes**, `ngClass` seems more convenient & compact.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install bootstrap in your project folder

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Then import bootstap css in your style.css file

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Now you can add simply boostrap class in your template inside component

```
<span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite" [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite" (click)="onclick()"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reader using **bootstrap 4** and having issue with **glyphicon**:

glyphicon has been dropped in bootstrap 4 [ [see](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18749) ]. So you may downgrade to v3 or use your own icon fonts.